# Prolog query doesn't return all answers

Tags: prolog

I'm just beginning to learn Prolog and I am using SWI-Prolog on Ubuntu. I'm watching a YouTube tutorial on Prolog where a query returns (infinite) correct answers, but on my computer the same query only returns one seemingly random answer.

---

Code: `vertical(line(point(X, Y), point(X, Y2)))`.

Query: `vertical(line(point(5, 10), X))`.

Expected tutorial output: `X = point(5, _ )`.

Actual output: `X = point(5,6058)`.

---

For a point `X` to be vertical with `(5,10)` it needs to have the form `(5, _ )`, but my output is `(5,6058)`. The output is also different for the same command the second time I run the query, and then it stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* a free variable. If we query this, we obtain:

```
?- vertical(line(point(5, 10), X)).
X = point(5, _3730).
```

Notice the underscore in `_3730`. That means that it is a variable. If you introduce a free variable, a Prolog interpreter will add a number to this. This is useful if there are multiple free variables, since it makes it clear which variables are the same, and which variables are different ones.

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem was the Visual Studio Code terminal always  displays empty spaces instead of showing the "_" (for some reason?) so I did not realize it was _6058. When I run it in a normal terminal, it is displayed properly.